# Error: Unsupported operation: Attempted to change a read-only message (EntityUiPb) in dart by using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, protocol-buffers

I am just making an object of Google protocol buffer which I named OrganisasationUiPb and organisationUipb contain another protocol buffer message EntityUipb

my code

```
OrganisationUiPb uipb = new OrganisationUiPb();
uipb.dbInfo.id = "add";
uipb.name.canonicalName = "add";
print(uipb);
```

OrganisationUiPb

```
message OrganisationUiPb {
EntityUiPb dbInfo = 1;
NameUiPb name = 2;
TimeUiPb time = 3;
string orgCode = 4;
```

}

EntityUipb

```
message EntityUiPb {
string id = 1;
int32 version = 2;
StatusEnum lifeTime = 3;
LocaleUiPb locale = 4;
```

}

when I make an object of OrganisationUipb and start assign values I got this error in cosole

```
Error: Unsupported operation: Attempted to change a read-only message (EntityUiPb)
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:49885/dart_sdk.js:4463:11)
at Object.defaultFrozenMessageModificationHandler (http://localhost:49885/packages/protobuf/src/protobuf/type_registry.dart.lib.js:5888:15)        
at protobuf._FieldSet.new.[_ensureWritable] (http://localhost:49885/packages/protobuf/src/protobuf/type_registry.dart.lib.js:2551:50)
at protobuf._FieldSet.new.[_validateField] (http://localhost:49885/packages/protobuf/src/protobuf/type_registry.dart.lib.js:3007:28)
at protobuf._FieldSet.new.[_$check] (http://localhost:49885/packages/protobuf/src/protobuf/type_registry.dart.lib.js:2800:27)
at protobuf._FieldSet.new.[_$set] (http://localhost:49885/packages/protobuf/src/protobuf/type_registry.dart.lib.js:2783:35)
at entityUiPb$46pb.EntityUiPb.__.$_setString (http://localhost:49885/packages/protobuf/src/protobuf/type_registry.dart.lib.js:3956:36)
at entityUiPb$46pb.EntityUiPb.__.set id [as id] (http://localhost:49885/packages/StudenceWebOrMObileUI/Protobuff/entityUiPb.pb.dart.lib.js:100:12) 
at Object.main$ [as main] (http://localhost:49885/packages/StudenceWebOrMObileUI/main.dart.lib.js:491:20)
at main$ (http://localhost:49885/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:14:12)
at main$.next (<anonymous>)
at http://localhost:49885/dart_sdk.js:37175:33
at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:49885/dart_sdk.js:37029:58)
at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:49885/dart_sdk.js:32116:29)
at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:49885/dart_sdk.js:32663:49)
at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:49885/dart_sdk.js:32701:17)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:49885/dart_sdk.js:32427:27)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:49885/dart_sdk.js:37290:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:49885/dart_sdk.js:37296:13)
at http://localhost:49885/dart_sdk.js:32918:9
```

and on UI I got

```
errors.dart:165 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unsupported operation: Attempted to change a read-only message (EntityUiPb)
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:214)
at Object.defaultFrozenMessageModificationHandler (field_set.dart:15)
at protobuf._FieldSet.new.[_ensureWritable] (field_set.dart:157)
at protobuf._FieldSet.new.[_validateField] (field_set.dart:794)
at protobuf._FieldSet.new.[_$check] (field_set.dart:512)
at protobuf._FieldSet.new.[_$set] (field_set.dart:493)
at entityUiPb$46pb.EntityUiPb.__.$_setString (generated_message.dart:456)
at entityUiPb$46pb.EntityUiPb.__.set id [as id] (entityUiPb.pb.dart:44)
at Object.main$ [as main] (main.dart:21)
at main$ (web_entrypoint.dart:9)
at main$.next (<anonymous>)
at async_patch.dart:45
at _RootZone.runUnary (zone.dart:1450)
at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (future_impl.dart:143)
at handleValueCallback (future_impl.dart:696)
at Function._propagateToListeners (future_impl.dart:725)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (future_impl.dart:393)
at Object._microtaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:41)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:50)
at async_patch.dart:166
```

please help me and provide solution of this so I can counter this problem

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that the Dart protobuf implementation creates an immutable default value for the child objects of `OrganisationUiPb`  so `uipb.dbInfo` is read-only from creation.

The workaround is to create the child object first, something like this:

```
EntityUiPb dbInfoTemp= new EntityUiPb();
dbInfoTemp.id = "add";
OrganisationUiPb uipb = new OrganisationUiPb()..dbInfo = dbInfoTemp;
...

print(uipb);
```

Mode discussion on the issue here:
https://github.com/dart-lang/protobuf/issues/305